# Textbox won't get selected date using jquery datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

src:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

script:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
        $("#datetimepicker1").on("change", function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();
            $("<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").val(selected)
        });
    });
</script>
```

designer:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtDate" class="control-label col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;preferred date </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepick"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
                <button type="button" id="datetimepicker1" class="common-button2"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Okay so, problem is, the calendar pops up, but the textbox won't get the selected date, all scripts are included and there were no errors. Please help thanks!

EDIT: Used the <%=txtDate.ClientID %> because my page has a master page.

Comment: where is the code for adding `datepicker`

Comment: Hi @coder edited, pls see thanks!

Comment: if you are using master page, then get the _ID_ by inspecting element from the browser.

Comment: Already did that, returns nothing @coder

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").val(selected)
```

is not a valid jquery selector

You want

```
   $("#txtDate").val(selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not using any Master page then Simply write

```
$("#txtDate").val(selected);
```

otherwise

```
$("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").val(selected);
```

'**#**' is important because it is indicates that this is an id.

Answer (score 0):

You are making your `datepicker` too tough to use.

Here is the simple solution

```
<p>
        Date:
        <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

JS:-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

See the [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v0xk8jeq/)

**UPDATE**

```
$(function () {
        $("#Id generated by inspecting element from browser").datepicker();
    });
```

Comment: then you need to put some more information about your code, as your Textbox takes ID inherited from master page

Comment: Nope, textbox is on a content page.

Comment: i said it is **INHERITED** from the master page. i didn't said its on master page. Thanks. Untill and unless you provide  more information about your code sorry we can't be able to detect your issue and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

jquery datepicker returns the selected value on **onSelect** event instead of onChange. try this

```
<script>
 $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }, onSelect: function(dateText) {
   $("<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").val(dateText)
  });

    });
</script>
```